# Grunt deleting index.html content

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I've noticed on a couple projects with Yeoman that when I run any of the the `grunt build`, `grunt serve` commands, content (script tags, link tags, the like) get deleted from my `index.html` file. Any ideas as to why this happens? And how to fix it. Seems to be happening with imports from my bower_components folder especially, but I've also had instances where the font-awesome cdn was deleted as well.

If it makes a difference, I'm developing for AngularJS using Yeoman.

Comment: Can you please provide your `Gruntfile.js`, and the problematic `index.html`? Without that it's not really possible to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this sometimes. The changed parts are enclosed in

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/......" />
......
<!-- endbower -->
```

or

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/....."></script>
......
<!-- endbower -->
```

The content in `bower:js/css` tag are generated from `bower.json`, so if the js/css files are not listed in `bower.json`, it will be removed from `bower:js/css`.

The good practice is to use `bower install  --save` or `bower install --save-dev` to install the dependency, it will update the `bower.json` automatically.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone has the same issue, take a look at @stephenplusplus comments in https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/545

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bit obvious, but you are editing the index.html in the app directory and not the dist/index.html copy?

The dist file will be overwritten by your app/index.html whenever you build

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution.

That happens due to the lack of information in the bower.json of the lib that you are using.

Debuging grunt build, I've discovered that the file is erased in the step 'wiredep'.

In the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep#bower-overrides), you have a part that says about problems.
Basically, if the bower.json of the lib doesnot have the file you need in the main node, the method wiredep will erase it.

For example, the angular-i18n, for translations.
the folder is:

```
angular-i18n/
           en-us.js
           pt-br.js
           bower.json
```

If you look to its bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-i18n",
  "version": "1.6.4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "components",
    "precommit.sh"
  ]
}
```

When you add: 
If you add to **your** bower.json this node, it will work:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-i18n": "^1.6.4"
  },
  "overrides" : {
    "angular-i18n" : {
      "main" : ["angular-locale_pt-br.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this help!